# What is a line launcher

Tags: mechanisms, projectiles

Okay, so I think that a line launcher is a device used in rescues?

What I’m unsure please about is how they work, like the Batman grapple gun (is that a line launcher) or like a line launcher gun please?

Also please, for a trebuchet or catapult please, how is the weight related to how far the thing is thrown please?

Comment: This question is a bit unfocused. You can post multiple separate questions that are more focused. No need to ball everything up into one. Line launchers are probably pneumatic though some may use gunpowder. Trebuchets use a counterweight. Catapults have no counterweight. They use twisted leather which acts as a spring. Did you try a Google search first? There are detailed results under "Trebuchet Physics": https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/trebuchet-physics.html

Comment: The basic concept should be closer to the crossbow the Catapult or Trebuchet, isn't it?

Comment: See [Lyle Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyle_gun), for one.

Answer (score 0):

Like a spear gun with a fishing line attached.

A classic concept based on a string tied around a rock which was first thrown then launched in a catapult then trebuchet etc

Comment: Hi, cheers Mike! How does a trebuchet launch stuff please? Isn’t that just a catapult?

Comment: In some applications ( Naval, seacoast, etc) a launcher is a small cannon.